# How do I reference a function parameter inside inside a data.table with a column of the same name?

Tags: r, data.table

Here, I have a data.table `foo`

```
foo <- data.table(t = c(1,1,2,2,3), b = rnorm(5))
foo
   t           b
1: 1  0.07014277
2: 1  1.71144087
3: 2 -0.60290798
4: 2 -0.47216639
5: 3 -0.63537131
```

and a function, `myfunc()`

```
myfunc <- function(dt, t){
  # Subset dt by t, then do stuff

  dt <- dt[J(t = t), by = "t"]
  
  # Complicated stuff here..
  score <- mean(dt$b)
  
  return(score)
}
```

`myfunc()` takes two parameters:

- `dt` the data.table to operate on
- `t` a value of t that can be used to subset `dt` (on the t *column*, of course)

My problem is, in my subset operation `dt <- dt[J(t = t), by = "t"]`, I can't figure out how to make R reference the function variable t for the second t. I've tried variations of `dt <- dt[J(t = get(t, -1)), by = "t"]` with no luck.

I know I should probably just change my function variable name, but in reality they are quite verbose and specific and I'd rather not. Also note that, in reality,  `myfunc()` is a complicated plotting function.

Comment: There's already a base R function named `t` so you would be well advised to start with something that won't be mistaken for that R object. You should also explain in more detail what you expect from this example, especially how `myfunc()` will be called I can't figure out from the (non-working) code what your goal really is.

Comment: Also ... how in heck do you expect us to return a mean of a character variable???

Comment: @IRTFM, oops. copy paster error. I've updated my example.. Also, I'm specifically using "t" because it *is* a base R function. I want to really wrap my head around scoping rules.

Comment: Strongly related: [Tidyverse  design principle: . prefix to all named arguments](https://design.tidyverse.org/dots-prefix.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. One possible option is this:

```
myfunc <- function(dt, t){
  env <- environment()
  dt <- dt[t==get('t',env)]
  mean(dt$b)
}
```

2. Another approach: while perhaps not strictly a "solution" to your current problem, you may find it of interest. Consider `data.table` version>= 1.14.3. In this case, we can use `env` param of `DT[i,j,by,env,...]`, to indicate the datatable column as `"t"`, and the function parameter as `t`. Notice that this will work on column `t` with function parameter `t`, even if `dt` contains columns named `col` and `val`

```
myfunc <- function(dt, t){
  dt <- dt[col==val, env=list(col="t", val=t)]
  mean(dt$b)
}
```

---

In both case, usage and output is as below:

Usage

```
myfunc(dt = foo, t = 3)
```

Output:

```
[1] 0.1292877
```

Input:

```
set.seed(123)
foo <- data.table(t = c(1,1,2,2,3), b = rnorm(5))
```

`foo` looks like this:

```
> foo
   t           b
1: 1 -0.56047565
2: 1 -0.23017749
3: 2  1.55870831
4: 2  0.07050839
5: 3  0.12928774
```

Answer (score 0):

The ambiguity is not at the level of base-function-`t` versus column named "t". It's at the level of parameter named `t` and column named `t`> Heres a modified function that succeeds (at least if there has been a setkey(foo, "t") operation prior:

```
myfunc <- function(dt, d){
    # Subset dt by t, then do stuff
    
    dt1 <- dt[ t==d]
    
    # Complicated stuff here..
    score <- dt1[ , paste(b, collapse="_")]
    
    return(score)
}

 myfunc(foo, d=1)
#[1] "a_b"
```

Obviously I need to come up with an interior function that made sense for a character variable column. This would seem to solve the apparent problem that you are having with a column named "t". Just change the name of the parameter in your function's parameter list to something other than "t". The scoping and environments in `data.table` j-calls (the expressions evaluated as the second arguments) are different than in regular R.

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like you've renamed the function parameter from "t" to "d" to avoid my scoping issue. I was specifically trying not to do this. Can you develop a solution that retains the parameter name *t*?

Comment: I believe this is missing the point of the question. For any toy example, yes, renaming the argument is an easy fix. I think the question is asking if we had, e.g., a production environment where a function with argument `t` is run on a lot of data where we have little control over the column names, there is a risk that there is a name collision between a column name and an argument name. Is there a more robust solution than (a) choosing an obscure argument name and hoping to not have collisions or (b) if there is a collision, doing special handling to, say, rename the column?

Comment: Note that, in my case, it's actually quite desirable to have the function parameter names match the column names in my data.table, because it clearly indicates which parameters will be used to subset corresponding columns. In other words, it makes sense to have a parameter named "t" that's used to subset column "t", but it's weird to have a parameter named "d" to subset column "t".

Comment: If you adopt the suggestion of adding a period ("dot") before the parameter name you could easily achieve you goal.